# How do I run a sock proxy via ssh on a non-standard port?

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I am running into a bit of trouble accessing a web application running on port 9293 on a remote server only accessible via ssh on port 5634. I've configured FoxyProxy to route all traffic meeting the remote host's IP address (wildcard white listed like so *remoteip*) to port 1234. The end to this story is it's not working, here is the ssh command I'm running:

```
ssh -D 1234 user@remoteip -p 5634
```

Then when I attempt to connect to the web app via the following address, it timesout (ssl is enabled):

```
https://remoteip:9293
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Also the remote host is running Debian 7.5, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `telnet` in order to check if the port forwarding works:

```
telnet localhost 1234
```

It's probably not working as you use the wrong `SSH` options (twice):

```
ssh -L localhost:1234:remoteip:5634 user@remoteip
```

or (depending on it on which interface(s) the server is listening:

```
ssh -L localhost:1234:localhost:5634 user@remoteip
```